# Case not returning value

Tags: vb.net

I have setup a select case in my text adventure, when the words 'inventory' and 'pickupblade/takeblade' are inputted a subroutine should be called. However, this subroutine is not being called despite the cases 1&2 calling the subroutine correctly. The code does not throw up any exceptions but the corresponding subroutine is not being called.

```
while playing
        console.write("Where to next? ")
        ' get the command from user
        command = console.readline()
        ' command should be of either a single verb, single direction, or verb noun
        ' parse the command then use verb to identify appropriate action to take
        commandWords = Split(command," ")
        select case ubound(commandwords)
            case 0
            ' 'verb' command
                select case ucase(commandWords(0))
                    case "N","S","E","W","NORTH","SOUTH","EAST","WEST"
                        if tryMoving(commandWords(0)) then displayRoom
                    case "INVENTORY"
                        if trymoving(commandwords(0)) then inventory
                    case "PICKUPBLADE", "TAKEBLADE"
                        if trymoving(commandwords(0)) then pickup_blade

                end select
            case 1
            ' 'verb noun' commands
                select case ucase(commandWords(0))
                    case "GO","MOVE"
                        if trymoving(commandwords(1)) then displayRoom
                end select

        end select


    end while
End Sub

sub displayRoom()
    console.title=room(location)
    console.out.writeline(desc(location))
    if objLocation(0) = location Then
        Console.WriteLine("You can see a blade")
        Console.WriteLine("You can pickup this item.")
    end if  
end sub

sub pickup_blade()
    if objLocation(0) = location Then
        Console.WriteLine("You have picked up the blade.")
        objLocation(0) = 0
    end if
end sub

sub inventory()
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------")
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------Inventory-----------------------")
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------")
    if objLocation(0) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("> Blade")
    elseif objLocation(1) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("> Gloves")
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Inventory is empty.")
    end if

end sub
```

Comment: You have `select case ubound(commandwords)` with `case 3` and `select case ucase(commandWords(0))`, looking for a match with "INVENTORY".  So your input command would have to have **3 spaces** in it...something like "INVENTORY what the bleep", when you're probably expecting it to work with simply "INVENTORY".

Comment: @Idle_Mind I have changed the code so now the 'INVENTORY' and 'PICKUPBLADE' command is under case 0. However, the subroutine is still not being called? I have updated the snippet showing the changes.

Comment: Are you sure `playing` is true?

Comment: @itsLex Yeah, `playing` is set true at the beginning of the program and the `"N","S","E","W"` commands all work

Comment: What does `trymoving()` do?  It doesn't seem to me like you would have to successfully "try moving" to execute an **inventory** command.  Most likely that function is returning false.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I figured it out, you were correct the `trymoving()` function was not needed for this type of command. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The `trymoving()` was not needed for this type of command.